# Warn answerers on close candidates

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close

A lot of duplicate questions pop up on Stack Overflow every day. Unfortunately many of the users who answer to those questions are not aware that it might be a duplicated. The close-voting system along with the review queue is a great tool.

However the close queue is huge and it often takes so much time until 5 votes come together. In the meanwhile the duplicates get new answers. The result is that good answers are spread across multiple questions. The closure of a question comes "too late", only after the main "wave" of answers has been posted already. After that the closure will be of marginal use (IMHO).

So here's the thing. What if all users that are about to answer a question are notified as soon as the first close vote was cast (in a similar way as the notification when a new answer was posted). That gives the user the possibility to refrain from answering, reviewing the close vote reasons, and then choose to cast another vote themselves, continue answering, or wait with the answer to see where the review and/or discussion is heading.

I'm slightly afraid that this question turns out as duplicate, too, but I did not find any matching question so far...

Comment: In addition, those with sufficient reputation already know when a close vote has been cast.  As you've already noted, the close queue is useless for this; close votes on a new question normally are cast by new viewers to the question, not by people in the Close Votes queue.

Comment: @Robert it's about preventing low-rep users from answering questions for which a duplicate exists.

Comment: The way you do that is by voting to close the question.  Once the question is closed, no more answers can be accepted.  Note that gold badge holders already have insta-close capability now.

Comment: Why that doesn't seem to work is explained by OP here. It's about users posting guess/try this-answers and answers copying information already on the site because they can't see the question is being nominated to be closed. The "possible duplicate of" comment never seems to deter people from answering, so a more prominent warning is being suggested here.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Why is that a problem, exactly?  All you folks looking at bad answers instead of bad questions.. You're looking at the wrong thing.

Comment: @Robert not necessarily bad answers, but answers that spread out knowledge and have to be reviewed on correctness. Or people who would have close-voted instead of answered when they saw the existing close votes.

Comment: @CodeCaster: As a general rule of thumb, folks should be voting to close on the basis of their own assessment of the question, not on how other people are voting.  Whatever you call the undesirable answers, they get removed with the question when the question is closed and deleted, and so does the reputation earned on those answers (if any).

Comment: @Robert - Unfortunately, the question with its answers is usually ***not*** removed, it is only closed. But it stays on Stackoverflow and adds to the hay rather than the needles. - I don't intend to influence the opinion of users. It is only about making them aware, for many of them seem not to check whether there are duplicates before they start to answer (and rats, it happens to me, too!). (I am not going to suggest to delete closed questions as I feel that it would be too radical - although I sometimes wish it would happen :-) )

Comment: @Robert - regarding "those... laready know when a close vote has been cast" - only if it was cast when you open the question. What if you start typing an answer and concurrently another user casts a close vote?

Answer (score 3):

If I am not mistaken the situation is very simple in general:

**If you want to alert people, place a comment**

---

That being said, I would probably favor such a message while you are writing an answer:

> A new comment has been posted

Comment: This is a nice idea, too. However it puts the caster in charge of the notification. I estimate that about <5% of the close-vote-casters will place a comment to notify potential answer authors.

Comment: @chiccodoro A number of different close-vote reasons auto-post comments... or is my browser infected with a helpful AI again?

Comment: @Yakk - no, you are right. Duplicates are one of those reasons :-) => +1

Comment: People ignore comments all the time.  Vote/close for dupe adds a comment, but those "low hanging fruit" questions will manage to rack up a couple of answers before it gets 4 more votes.  For unclear questions, I've left comments where someone wrote essentially the same thing as an answer hours later.