# Notification for answers of closed questions as animation to edit the question

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, answers, notifications

Similar to [Warn answerers on close candidates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256352) I think that answering bad questions isn't really helping the site. While that [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) is mostly about warning users that are about to answer (and mostly targeting duplicate questions) there are also cases where the question is answered before even the first close vote.

I therefore propose we add a feature that people who answered a question that got closed, get notified about it. Depending on the close reason, the notification can ask for possible actions.

#### closed as duplicate

Look at the duplicate and decide if you want to move your answer there, or if it is already present at the duplicate and you want to delete it here

#### closed as unclear

It seems you have understood the question, but a lot of other people did not. Please take some time and edit the question so that it will be clearer for future visitors how your answer answers it.

#### others

Explain a bit about the reason why it was closed and motivate to improve the question if possible, or revoke the answer.

Comment: I imagine that the majority of people who answer questions that end up closed don't really *care*, and would just ignore the notifications, but if even some of these users respond by either fixing the question, or recognizing that these types of questions shouldn't be answered (whether or not they delete *that* answer) then this is helping the site.

Comment: @Servy: Indeed. I doubt there are solutions that will get rid of all problematic users, but reducing them one by one might one day get them down to a level that we can all live with fine.