# Should we be more obnoxious about not allowing people to waste time answering questions that are closed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It's happened more than once, but it's a major frustration.  The scenario goes like this:

- OP asks a question that *on the surface* has a simple answer
- The example code reveals there's actually more than one issue going on
- Someone answers the easy surface problem right away
- You are in the middle of a long write up that addresses the other underlying problems--i.e. design issues, and these take time to write
- The question is marked as a duplicate before the longer post can be submitted
- **All that time spent answering the real issue is wasted** because the in-progress answer can't be submitted now.

So, is there any way to allow people with an already in-progress answer to **actually post what they typed up** even if someone else marked it a duplicate?  **Or at the very least close the editing window** on the person who is typing up their longer response so that they don't waste any more time than they have to?

In all honesty, the second option would be frustrating, but my time is important.  I would rather be prevented from typing any longer.  Don't make it look like I can keep going but subtly make the submit button unusable.  I'm not going to see that until I'm completely done with my answer and it's too late.

Comment: There is a grace period where you can still post through a closure when you were already typing an answer, and you should see a bar saying something like _"This question has now been closed and new answers won't be accepted"_ after that grace period, but both seem to fail to work more often than they do work.

Comment: If your answer is long enough that bar is off screen and seen far too late.

Comment: I think the bar appears (when it does work) on top of the viewport and not the top of the page, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: Considering this scenario just happened to me, I can tell you the notification is far too easily missed.  I didn't see it until I was done with my answer and double checking the code--and the submit button wouldn't work.

Comment: It is simple: you should have looked for a duplicate in the first place before typing. You're wasting your own time.

Comment: It's not so simple.  It wasn't really just a duplicate. As mentioned the "duplicate" was the easy surface answer

Comment: @Tunaki that is irrelevant to this question and rather quite a hostile remark that should be worded a bit more friendly. Perhaps they tried to find a duplicate but couldn't find one.

Comment: Okay, fair enough @CodeCaster. If it isn't a duplicate, you _can_ vote to reopen and post it afterwards. If it is a duplicate, you _can_ post it on the duplicate (if it applies).

Comment: I don't have great confidence that my pending answer won't get discarded forcing me to retype everything.  So the question is how forceful do we want to be.  I think there needs to be a change.  It's a question of essentially booting someone from typing any longer, or being more accepting of an already in-progress answer.  Voting to reopen afterwards is a tangential issue.

Comment: @Berin on the other hand, if typing on the web has taught me anything in the past fifteen or so years, it's that you do a Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C to at least save your text to the clipboard before clicking any link or button. Works less well for forms with many inputs though.

Comment: So, instead of just clicking a down vote: why not post an answer explaining why you think the status quo is better than what I proposed?  Since this here for discussion, let's put it out there.  Or is the question itself of poor quality?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276597/better-notification-of-closed-question-in-process-of-being-answered, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258624/notification-for-answers-of-closed-questions-as-animation-to-edit-the-question, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310144/questions-being-closed-as-answers-are-being-written, etc...

Comment: @ayhan Everyone is already notified when the question they are on is closed or deleted. Can/Should it be made more "in-your-face obnoxious"? That's a different debate.

Comment: @Deduplicator, That **is** this debate.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Well, the existing hints are enough for me usually.

Comment: If you found a deeper truth that isn't revealed by existing Q+A then simply ask the question yourself.  In a way that doesn't make everybody go for the obvious non-truth.   And post the answer you already typed.

Comment: @CodeCaster The grace period only applies to users who weren't notified that the question was closed, most often because their browser doesn't support the live refresh features (happens to me quite often on mobile). The grace period itself is *four hours*. It's not short.

Comment: @Kevin _every_ question can be answered by combining a few canonical duplicates. That's all there is to programming: breaking up a problem into smaller problems you do know (or can find out) how to solve. The problem is that the OP doesn't know in such cases how to do the breaking up, nor about the existence of the smaller, solved problems. That's called experience. Oh, or remove your comment.

Comment: @animuson, then I guess the problem is for people with partial outages.  I.e. _some_ autoupdate work but whatever pops up a notification does not.

Comment: The solution is to [hit that edit button](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261492/give-high-rep-users-immunity-from-closure-when-answering/261574#261574). Early and often.

Answer (score 4):

If a question has multiple problems, that suggests the question is too broad or unclear, and the question should not be answered until the asker has narrowed or clarified it.

If it often happens that the question is closed while you are writing an answer, this suggests you are too keen to answer low quality questions, rather than ignoring them or voting to close them. Answering low quality questions might seem helpful, but it is actually counterproductive. This is not meant to be a help site. It is meant to create a repository of good questions with good answers.

Answer (score -6):

It's my personal opinion that the current alert implementation is not sufficient.  It's too easy for corporate proxy server (mis)configurations to break the functionality in subtle ways.  **Some of the websockets stuff works, but a lot doesn't from my location**.

I would much rather have a more heavy handed approach to kill the edit box that I'm working in than a simple notification that may or **may not** appear.  As long as I can copy/paste my answer out of the page, but no longer edit, it would be far better than what happens here.

The other alternative is to let me post what I was already in the middle of, and/or extend the grace period which is still too short.

Comment: Well, they have [a workaround](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) for that as well.

Comment: @HansPassant, who says that's not in the works... problem is most companies in my area have overzealous IT staff.  I'm just happy I can get to this site at all.  You never know until you make your switch what you really get.