# Can a header notification be added to indicate a new question has been held or deleted?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, closed-questions, deleted-questions, locked-posts

When a new question is posted, but then put on hold or deleted, is there a way to send a 'Red X' or some similar notification to users viewing/responding to the question to indicate that the question can no longer be answered? It is a tad frustrating to be working on an answer for a while only to click answer, or click comment, and have the red box appear telling you you can no longer answer? Just looking for a way to save wasted time. I apologize if this has already been addressed. The closest I found in the list was a thread that discussed notification when old posts were deleted rather than current.

And since every suggestion is 'nit-picked', let me be clear, the 'Red-X' is just an example of a type of notification and not a direct request for a 'Red-X'. I don't care what type of indication is sent as long as something provides notice that the question being viewed has been deleted or put on-hold before you press the answer or comment button. It could be something as simple as putting up 'Closed' or 'On-Hold' next to the inbox notification, or yes, even a red 'X' Thanks.

Comment: There should be a [grace period granted for answering](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79457/153020) questions you started to answer before they were put on hold. Doing something for deleted or locked sounds sensible though.

Comment: Related [Warn answerers on close candidates](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256352/warn-answerers-on-close-candidates?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'm just old and slow (and have kids under 10) so questions take a while to answer.

Comment: If you see a question is getting downvotes or/and close votes then there is probably something wrong with it and therefore you do not answer it

Comment: Well, that was what prompted the post. Many times there is no indication at all. No downvotes, no possible duplicate comments, you just work away for 5-10 min. and click answer and surprise it's closed. None of these are biggies, they just add polish to an already good site.

Answer (score 1):

This already exists:

[image: This question has been closed - no more answers will be accepted.]

[image: This question has been deleted - no more answers will be accepted.]
[image: This question has been locked - no more answers will be accepted.]

It's not instant; there's a periodic check that runs while you're writing the answer which will notify you if the answer can't be posted, so you'll generally see these pop up a few seconds to a minute *after* the question is closed/deleted/locked. This also means you won't find out if you lose Internet connectivity or disable JavaScript, but... that's pretty much unavoidable.

Comment: They definitely show up without first submitting the answer; I grabbed these screenshots by just closing / deleting / locking a question on which I had a half-composed answer in a different window, and they faded in ~a minute later.

Comment: This might be a good time to point out that the "grace period" (which people presumably get because their browsers don't work properly.  What is it nowadays.. *four hours?*) is rather at odds with the apparent 1 to 5 minute delay for this banner.

Comment: Not really, @Robert - the point of the notification is to warn folks away from answering a question that'll probably just end up deleted; the point of the grace period is to avoid losing their work if they do it anyway. In the (admittedly unlikely) scenario that someone spends 3 hours offline working on an answer, throwing away that much of their work would be... bad.

Comment: Oh.  Well, in my browser, if I get the closed banner, I am locked out from posting my pending answer (unless I employ some Javascript trickery to override the disabled button).

Comment: Sure - but it doesn't *discard* your answer. The grace period exists for folks who don't / can't get the banner. (It also predates the banner by a good bit, IIRC)

Comment: Doesn't seem altogether fair for us folks who don't use broken browsers, does it?

Comment: Not sure there's normally an advantage to answering a closed question. It's easy enough to achieve in those situations that warrant it.