# A proposal to put all answerers on a path to curating better content

Tags: feature-request, answers, low-quality-posts, post-ban, users

What's not working well and why:

1. New users very, very, very seldom understand the difference between a good, clear, unique, on-topic question and a question that should be closed.  In fact, we have high frequency volunteers with hundreds of thousands of rep who habitually answer questions that should be closed.
2. New users are compelled to answer "quickly" because they fear that other volunteers will provide the same advice faster.  Couple this with the fact that new contributors are inexperienced with the formatting tools in the post editor and [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), then you can understand why many of these posts are some of the lowest quality contributions site-wide.  Competing for speed is not conducive to building an awesome repository of knowledge.  **A [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533) culture actually damages the ultimate goal.**
3. [Users with less than 15 reputation simply do not have the ability to flag the closure of a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) that should be closed.  So **of course they are blissfully unaware of the importance of curating good content**!  I mean, [users don't even get to **see** when there are close votes on a question until they reach 250 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes), so I find myself commenting things like **Off-topic: Typo** to try to ward off not-yet-posted answers while additional close votes are garnered. And finally, [users don't unlock the close vote privilege until they reach 3000 rep points!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

---

### Proposal: Impose answer blocking on inexperienced answerers and answerers with a glaring track record of answering questions that should be closed instead.

The details:

- Answer blocking only ever involves the freshest posted questions -- posted within the last 4 hours.  Blocking never prohibits users from answering *all* questions on the site.
- If a user has fewer than 5 posted answers, they are deemed too inexperienced to be trusted to differentiate between good and bad questions.
- If 60% or more of a user's most recent answers have been on closed questions, the block is imposed and a warning box will be presented which explains the block and lists the closed pages.
- There are three ranges of "recent answers" being checked.  The most recent 5, 10 and 20 answers.
  This should be sufficient in targeting users with indubitably unwanted contributions.

I'll cherry-pick some content from the [new user privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user#:%7E:text=Why%20are%20restrictions%20placed%20on%20new%20users?) which shares the exact purpose of this proposal:

> [...]we must take some precautions to ensure that the [...] user doesn't ruin the experience for everyone else.

What I am proposing is the second evolution of [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397526/2943403) which has many up and down votes and a plethora of comments that clearly didn't understand the mechanics of how the proposal is designed to work.

This proposal is designed to:

1. give inexperienced contributors (users with fewer than 5 answers) time to post well-crafted answers to good, vetted questions
2. allow new users the ability to remove this restriction through good posting behaviors even without earning a single upvote or green tick
3. uncouple privileges from rep -- which has proven to be a somewhat unreliable metric
4. reduce the likelihood of low-quality answers gaining upvotes (when the contributor is deemed untrusted and the block is imposed) -- this will allow curators to better manage/curate unhelpful content on old questions *and* help the Roomba to have an easier time of automatically cleaning up new unwanted questions.
5. groom the community to pause and consider the appropriateness of a question before they spray an answer on the page
6. equally impact *all* users from 1 rep to >1,000,000 rep and is completely ignorant of quality/volume of their posted *questions*
7. be effective yet fair on contributors -- even contributors that post tens of answers in a short period of time and the page closures don't come until later
8. signal contributors that they might potentially:

   - recalibrate their view of what a good/on-topic question is or
   - put more effort into finding duplicates before answering or
   - delete an answer to a closed question (a path to removing the block) or
   - vote to reopen a question that was inappropriately closed (a path to removing the block) or
   - edit an unclear question to make it clear/on-topic (a path to removing the block)
9. influence answerers to *care* about questions that they answer, by editing it into the the best possible shape before they move on so that it doesn't risk being closed
10. spare me from asking answerers to close bad questions instead of answering them -- the system will spell this out where truly necessary

One of the concerns from the earlier linked meta page asked if this proposal would simply shift the rubbish from new pages to old pages and make curation harder to do.  To this I say no.  This proposal will get answerers to start digging through historic content and fill knowledge gaps.  If  a necropost is not unique or valuable, then it will not generate any upvotes from the *Upvote Pixies* (users who sprinkle upvotes on the freshest of new questions) and this will make it much easier for human curators to downvote and delete the unwanted content.

If you have already lit up your torch and grabbed your pitchfork, stop and consider how often this block will *actually* be imposed.  After a user has 5 or more posted answers, it should be very hard to trigger this block if they are doing the right thing. I am personally curious if a SEDE query can be crafted which shows a snapshot of how many users would be blocked by the described rules.  I also wonder if certain language tags are more likely than others to trigger an answer block because of rampant bad answering and/or a collection of SMEs that do a lot of closing.  This proposal is intentionally revolutionary and some people might find it a little risky/scary.  I would be very happy to see it given a chance for a month or so and see how the community is impacted.

---

### I've made a toy for you to play with! 
<sup><sub>(see collapsed snippet for demo)</sub></sup>

I have created a basic JavaScript demonstration to show the effects of posting answers, then as questions are closed or as answers are deleted, an account's percentage of answers on open/closed questions can be recalculated.

Click the <kbd>+</kbd> button five or more times to simulate "posted answers".  Change the radio buttons to simulate the open/closed status of the question answered.  Click the <kbd>-</kbd> button to demonstrate how the deletion of a question/answer can potentially impose/remove the answer block.  I recommend using the StackSnippet in full screen mode.  [Screenshot of a user being blocked because of too many answers on closed pages.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOAdp.jpg)

###### Demonstration:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.add', function() {
  let mostRecentAnswer = $('#summary').prev(),
      id = !mostRecentAnswer.length ? 1 : 1 + mostRecentAnswer.data('id');
  $('#summary').before(
    '<tr data-id=' + id + '>'
      + '<td><input type="button" class="del" value="-"></td>'
      + '<td>'
        + '<label for="open' + id + '"><input type="radio" id="open' + id + '" name="status' + id + '" checked> Open</label>'
        + '<label for="closed' + id + '"><input type="radio" id="closed' + id + '" name="status' + id + '"> Closed</label>'
      + '</td>'
      + '<td class="newest5 hide"></td>'
      + '<td class="newest10 hide"></td>'
      + '<td class="newest20 hide"></td>'
    + '</tr>'
  );
  handleNewest();
});
$(document).on('click', '.del', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  handleNewest();
});
$(document).on('change', '[type="radio"]', function() {
  handleNewest();
});
function handleNewest() {
  let totalAnswers = $('#demo tr[data-id]').length;
  if (totalAnswers < 5) {
    $('#outcome').html('<b class="red">Please post carefully constructed and educational answers to questions which are at least 4 hours old -- it is presumed that this community has had ample to time to vet these new questions as clear, complete, unique and on-topic.</b>');
    return;
  }
  $('#outcome').html('More than 40% of your recent answers have been on open questions which the community has deemed to be a good fit for our repository of knowledge.');
  [5, 10, 20].forEach(function(group) {
    $('td[class^="newest' + group + '"]').addClass('hide').removeClass('groupStart groupEnd');
    if (totalAnswers >= group) {
      let lastCount = group - 1,
          sumOpen = 0,
          row = $('#summary').prev(),
          groupCell;
      for (let i = 0; i < group; ++i) {
        sumOpen += $('td label input[id^="open"]:checked', row).length;
        groupCell = $('td[class^="newest' + group + '"]', row);
        groupCell.removeClass('hide');
        if (!i) {
          groupCell.addClass('groupEnd');
        } else if (i === lastCount) {
          groupCell.addClass('groupStart');
        }
        row = row.prev();
      }
      let percent = Math.round(sumOpen / group * 100);
      $('#newest' + group + 'Total').html(percent).toggleClass('red', percent <= 40);
        $('td[class^="newest' + group + '"]:not(.hide)').toggleClass('redBG', percent <= 40);
        if (percent <= 40) {
          $('#outcome').html('<b  class="red">' + (100 - percent) + '% of your last ' + group + ' answers have been on closed pages. Please take more care to only post answers to clear, complete, unique, on-topic questions.</b>');
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

```css
#demo { border-spacing: 0; }
.newest5:not(.hide), .newest10:not(.hide), .newest20:not(.hide) { border-right: 1px solid black; min-width: 30px; }
.groupStart { border-top-right-radius: 30px; }
.groupEnd { border-bottom-right-radius: 30px; }
#summaryLabel { text-align: right; }
#[id$="Total"]:after { content: '%'; }
.red { color: red; }
.newest5.redBG:not(.hide), .newest10.redBG:not(.hide), .newest20.redBG:not(.hide) { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="demo">
  <tr id="summary">
    <td><input type="button" class="add" value="+"></td>
    <td id="summaryLabel">Open Percent:</td>
    <td id="newest5Total"></td>
    <td id="newest10Total"></td>
    <td id="newest20Total"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h2 id="outcome"></h2>
```

Self-answers should be excluded from this blocking mechanism.  Self-answered questions are not typically rushed or low-quality. In my experience, these usually meaningful contributions and are not worth blocking by default. It would be counter-productive to prevent users from instantly self-answering if they have something important to share.

Comment: *"New users are compelled to answer "quickly" because they fear that other volunteers will provide the same advice faster."* - Honestly I'm convinced that's more of an old user problem

Comment: We already have an Answer-ban.

Comment: We already throttle users who have a record of providing poor quality questions or answers. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide

Comment: @RobertLongson The rate limit on answers that you linked makes no attempt to do the things that my proposal aims to do.

Comment: @Scratte are you suggesting what Robert has linked to?  or something else?

Comment: Well the question ban is secret so who's to say it's not very similar to what you're proposing. The point is why is what you're suggesting better than what's already implemented?

Comment: I am absolutely sure that there is an extreme lack of awareness in new and veteran users regarding the importance of curation and deciding whether or not to answer a question.  I am 5xdupe hammering common questions (questions that have at least 5 duplicates and I link them explicitly) every day -- and yet we still have new users and users >100k who are posting answers to these mega-duplicate questions.  Also, **I am not talking about users being able to ask questions** -- I am talking about locking users from answering fresh questions.

Comment: On the contrary, I believe stack overflow needs *more* answers, not *fewer*, given the abysmal answer rate compared to other SE sites.

Comment: @user000001 This proposal makes not attempt to reduce the number of answers that are received.  What it endeavors to do is point new and problem contributors to pages that have already been vetted as good, clear, complete, unique, and on-topic.  Think of all of the contributor time and effort that is wasted when we close and delete bad pages.  This proposal endeavors to make better use of volunteer time (contributors & curators alike).

Comment: @user000001 isn't the abysmal answer rate because we get a flood of bad questions that we literally cannot stem the tide of? That does have an effect of the good questions also being occasionally overlooked.

Comment: @VLAZ: I dunno, personally I think all this is caused by not showing the right questions to the right people, and by not rewarding the good answers enough, but that's not at all trivial to solve.

Comment: @user000001 that will rely on some sort of quality mechanism. Which already implies hiding or in other ways reducing visibility and interactions with low quality content.

Comment: @mickmackusa Can you clarify what *"If a user has fewer than 5 posted answers, they are deemed too inexperienced"* means? If you have <5 answers you can't answer questions newer than 4 hours?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Correct.  Even if you have been a member of Stackoverflow for 10 years, have posted 1000 questions, have 20K rep -- the rule still applies.  We need a sufficient sample of answering history to figure out if you can be trusted "as an answerer" to do what is beneficial for Stack Overflow.  Until a user has 5 posted answers, they are not permitted to answer any questions that are under 4h old. Fringe possibility: a contributor _could_ post five separate answers to their own single question - after 4h of course. ...Hmm, I didn't consider cases of self-answering. Thought?

Comment: Doesn't that just make it much harder for a new good answerer to get into the game? And favour old answerers? I mean you can have 20K Answers in total and 25% on closed post, and still get to post quick [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/what-is-fgitw-and-scite) Answers with your proposal, no?

Comment: @Scratte We never look deeper than 20 answers back in the history.  A new good answerer will have no trouble finding good questions that are at least 4 hours old among the MILLIONS of pages that are available.  What this proposal will do, by consequence, is make it harder to gather loads of upvotes on their first 5 answers -- because the Upvote Pixies will not see their contributions.

Comment: I feel like lumping together closed-answers-bans and new-user-delays just complicates this. Both of these seem to have some issues worth pondering first, but combining them just adds the negative from one to the other as well.

Comment: Well, new answerers and non-new answers are equally contributing to the high noise-to-signal ratio on Stack Overflow.  There is a real lack of understanding in the vast majority of contributors.  New users specifically, come here, they see a question that they can answer and they have absolutely no idea that it is better to close basic duplicates instead of answering them.  This is why we need to give the community more time to vet pages before they can post an answer.  This is not about punishing new users (or veteran users); this is about grooming users to be better contributors.

Comment: We don't prohibit comments from new users because we are punishing them.  We do it so that the site is easier to keep clean and orderly.  This proposal does the same thing.

Comment: The solution is pretty simple to fight this: downvote, downvote and downvote again. Close vote, delete vote and so on. The users you are talking about are here for the Rep, if you downvote their answers they will delete it (they got afraid of the -2)

Comment: Nope. @Temani If that worked, I wouldn't have spent so much time creating this proposal.  New users with 1 rep lose nothing when I dv.  Then when a uv comes along from Upvote Pixies who want SO to be welcoming, it is like my attempted curation didn't occur at all.  High reppers are not phased by dvs when they know their correct answer will eventually get an uv or green tick.  The traditional techniques aren't working.  This is my daily frustration.  People (myself included) do not delete a dv'ed answer if they know/believe it is correctly answers the question.  They have zero concern.

Comment: Figuring out how Stack Overflow works takes some time for a new user, generally a new user would simply look to answer what the site shows to them first (after perhaps applying some tag filters), which usually is new questions. If there is a 4 hour barrier any new user who is potentially a good answerer would simply be disinclined to provide answers. There are 3 basic privileges a new user has this proposal basically cuts short the answering one. This essentially means it is easier for questioners to join rather than answerers (We want more answerers! at least I believe so).

Comment: Oh my God people.  There will ALWAYS be literally MILLIONS OF QUESTIONS to answer -- even with the block imposed.  This proposal stops no one ever.  It merely steers untrusted users away from fresh questions.

Comment: close question and delete them. You can never ever fight against users who want to spam the site with the same answers or bad answers because the system is designed to allow them to do so. The only way to fight this is to close questions and later delete them. We need to invite people to delete more and more questions especially the million duplicates that Roomba won't get them.

Comment: @Temani also I cannot be on SO all the time to stand guard.  I have a job and a family and other interests and need to sleep every once in a while.  I am woefully outnumbered by users who do not know or care about content curation.  This proposal helps the system to protect itself instead of relying on SMEs manually downvoting as a failed attempt to groom users.  I predict the mere threat of being blocked from the freshest questions will be a very powerful deterrent to those looking to farm rep.

Comment: @Nick & mickmackusa sounds like you're describing people who are farming rep. Both low rep or high rep users can engage in that.

Comment: related: [Tell answer-author when the question is being voted to close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322503/165773) at MSE and [Warn answerers on close candidates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256352/839601) here at MSO

Comment: "Upvote Pixies".. name calling other users because you don't like the way they vote. Is that what we are? Do we call other users names if we don't like their actions? Would you like one yourself? I'm sure not everyone agrees with your actions.

Comment: Thanks for this very well developed and well written proposal. Unfortunately, even if it was more favorably received here, it is unlikely that anything would change. Innovation is not in the company's DNA.

Comment: @Scratte On Meta, you'll find many instances of user labelling.  I've read terms as ugly as "rep whore" and as benign as "gold badgers".  My proposal is already super long and I am trying to allow brevity in future conversations by offering a term to describe the users who ONLY upvote the freshest content and seldom differentiate between answers which are correct/incorrect/advisable/dangerous.  I have been here for a good long time and have personally observed these voters undermining good curation attempts.  People call me name too.  I was called a "boar" in recent chat.  Labels happen.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I always knew my proposal would be negatively voted in Meta (again).  Those that curate and are trying to make a world-class repository of knowledge that is a researcher's paradise are massively outnumbered by people who don't care at all about the end effects of loose content generation and wish SO to be a Help Desk for people who do not research/try.  We are trapped in a downward spiral -- those who don't care/know about being careful are increasing in numbers and those who care/know are burning out and going away.  If SO can't change, there'll be calls for a new platform.

Comment: @mickmackusa I don't see the difference between any of those labels. Brevity isn't an excuse. You're trying to label them over in "that group of unwanteds". You don't seem to have any data to even support your "findings", and make even further claims about "those users". I've seen curators undermine good editing and good posting. Do you really think labeling curators by whatever I can think of for brevity is going to help anything? And the latest comment is also uncalled for. The "you're either with me or you don't care about the site"-type argument is not valid.

Comment: @Scratte I'm not going to run down the rabbit hole with you.  If you are offended by or think other people will be offended by the term, then edit it out of the question and flag the comments.  I do not agree that it is offensive.  I use the term to describe a behavior -- because of course we cannot specific users' voting actions.  I have personally seen the pattern of unmerited upvotes on answers to very fresh questions AND I've seen that these upvotes do not land on answers that are posted hours later.

Comment: Again a post which heavily discriminates new users. Stop - doing - that. Your post very much applies to the entire user base, not just new users. I'd actually speak for new users because they are basically making mistakes, there is no excuse for the chunk of people whom willingly treat this site like a helpdesk.

Comment: @Gimby I'm not sure I following which way you are arguing.  My proposal routes answerers to questions which have had sufficient time to be curated by the community.  When contributors demonstrate that they can differentiate between good/bad questions, then they will be welcome to post on fresh questions if they like.  The fresh questions block is only imposed on users with inexperience or a high percentage of answering on closed questions.  It is entirely possible that a 1-repper can post 5 answers and remove the block without a single upvote earned (in say an hour of posting).

Comment: Please see the leading statement of facts in my question.  New users do not have the ability to comment or flag -- because they haven't proven themselves to be trustworthy yet.  My proposal never STOPS a new user from posting answers -- it just shifts their attention to questions that have had plenty of time to be vetted and edited by the community.  There will always be millions of questions for them to answer.  They can take their time to become familiar with the post editor toolbar and carefully craft their answers with the intent to educate instead of speed rep farming.

Comment: Yes, answers on low quality questions that should be closed instead are part of the problem. But, we have the problem in the first place because we lack capability to deal with all those questions. Your proposal, while I could object to some of your points, basically just doesn't scale - and its main flaw is that it depends on the low quality questions being closed - and we are back to square one.

Comment: I designed this proposal to scale.  It is much more scalable than asking the community to manually flag, and moderators manually issuing full-blown suspensions. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508 @DalijaPrasnikar

Comment: You may think it scales, but is does not. You still have issue with high reputation FGITW users that answer 20+ questions daily, where most of the questions they answer will never be closed. Your proposal will only selectively prevent some users from answering, creating even more dissatisfaction and frown upon curators and as the end result very little will be accomplished. Solving original problem, low quality questions is the only way. We could add more warnings before users post their answers, hoping that at least some will pay attention, but more drastic measures will not do any good.

Comment: You seem to not believe me but I am 100% sure that this is a scalable solution.  If one basic dupe question attracts 5 FGITW answers before it is closed, then 5 answerers will receive this bad mark.  If they agree with the closure, they will be inclined to self-delete their answer without any human prompting because of the threat of being blocked from fresh questions where the rep points flow from more than just the OP.  If they disagree with the closure, then the OP will find community support for reopening. If answerers can edit the question to become openable, then that is a win too.

Comment: This proposal helps me to do the curation that I do every day.  I will no longer need to type out comments to individual users to say "please close duplicate questions instead of answering them" -- and I do this A LOT.  It also means that low-quality answers that are on non-fresh questions will be easier to curate/downvote/delete or even compel the answerers to remove (because they won't lose any rep points from the deletion).  Alternatively, when FGITW answers hit a question in 120 seconds, upvotes rain on it from multiple users and curation is made much more difficult.

Comment: "then 5 answerers will receive this bad mark".. then 5 users will be even more eager to re-open the post. Now you have battles that doesn't even need to be there. Note that this will just create a greater divide, since higher reputation users can easily cast reopen votes.

Comment: @Scratte maybe they will vote to reopen or maybe they will agree with the closure.  That is too situational to debate here.

Comment: The entire post is situational. Your proposal has assumptions that cannot be verified, yet you seem to claim that it would work. "they will be inclined to self-delete their answer".. that's just an assumption.

Comment: They will be _more_ inclined than normal to self-delete an answer to a closed question if there is a process that prohibits them from answering new questions.  I agree, there is not statistical support that my proposal will work.  Let's run it after the Winter Bash.  See what happens if we implement this for all of January 2022.  In 30 days, the gained awareness should be awesome and permanent.

Comment: @Scratte stop antagonizing the mickmack. He's cool. He needs plenty of support. This whole post is beautiful, I don't understand it, but it has character, passion, verbosity, over-elaboration, it's courteous and engaging, what else could we want? (Yeah if you answer 1000 dups you get a cool-off, simple enough.) Watch out all ye dupers.

Comment: @bad_coder I don't share your opinion about the adjectives to use for this post. Though I agree that it's verbose. But it seems to be fixed on "the solution". I don't think punishing people is a good way to solve a general problem. I certainly don't think creating a larger divide of users will help with anything. Harsh almost never makes anything better. Not to mention that I'm being label in a group here as an unwanted.

Comment: Let me put it this way, the problem being discussed here is in reality a symptom of a bigger problem: people posting duplicate / bad questions. Why insist on treating the symptoms? Focus on the real problem: downvote, close, delete the question and move on, do you really believe this 4 hour barrier would dissuade users who answer such questions? This solution in reality is only problematic for new users, for the other people who regularly post such answers it really won't stop them.

Comment: The system identifies answered questions (not closed) as "well received".  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262814/2943403 By fostering a "who cares" culture to curation, askers and answerers make no attempts to change because they are unaware that they are doing unhelpful things.  The 4 hour exclusion give the community time to edit/close/curate questions.  It seems the worst pain point in my proposal is the <5 answers rule.  Perhaps I should repost my proposal and strip out that rule and see if it, too, gets downvoted to oblivion.

Comment: I was just able to convince a user to post their answer to an un-attempted, 3x-dupe question on one of my nominated dupes and delete their answer on the new page (to allow the Roomba to work).  This is a curation win because we have better eggs in fewer baskets.  The bad news is, it doesn't scale.  I had to post 4 handwritten comments to the user to explain why and how I hoped he would change his actions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68803916/2943403 Yes, the human touch is nice but it doesn't move fast enough for the deluge of bad content that needs curation.

Comment: "The 4 hour exclusion give the community time to edit/close/curate questions." That's the part I don't get. The proposal seems to aim at us getting fewer bad answers, it does not mean we get fewer bad questions – yet questions are what needs curating. A 4 hour delay seems not to reduce the throughput of questions, nor to increase the throughput of curators.

Comment: @Scratte who said you were being labeled unwanted? Where?

Comment: You are a genius @mickmackusa !! You just solved the outstanding issue by coining the term *unwanted post*. That's sheer brilliance and descriptive power. No more need for *turd polishing* now it's *edits to unwanted posts*.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi if we have less people answering and more people closing then we will have fewer open/active questions. This will fundamentally shift the carefree culture of posting and begin the transition to higher value contributions.  I am curating questions feverishly everyday. I am not always the first to a page, so I find myself repeatedly asking answers to close instead of answering closable pages.  This is not scaling because there aren't enough mickmackusas online (not even enough just for the php questions where I swim). If there were no answers, the Roombe will be far more effective.

Comment: I don't think it should require much imagination to envision the ripple effect of grooming SMEs (regardless of their rep) to start doing more curation.  This proposal intends  to shepherd their actions toward curation instead of spraying answers mindless just because they _can_ answer.  The new initial thought should be "**Should** I answer?".

Comment: @mickmackusa I too see the current setup not scaling - which is why frankly I have given up. But I don't see how this proposal would help. Sure, I see how the proposal *might* lead to less answers. Yet I don't see how it would lead to more closing. I don't see where the ripple effect should come from. There are after all two means to answer fewer closed questions - from my negative experience with curators vs helpdeskers, my imagination tends towards the pessimistic option. Why should the optimistic be more likely?

Comment: Consider for example the regex tag as an extreme - one that is a template for and bleeding into other tags, though. Were helpdeskers open to their behavior being negative and harmful? Were they open to see the need to cooperate and curate? Or did they just publicly pillory curators without any consequences?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I envision this proposal as been revolutionary (aided greatly if combined with over awareness raising changes to Help pages and potentially rep-earning from close-voting).  Here's why I am optimistic: the mental shift from answer-unconditionally to consider-closing-first will be like a necklace sliding off a tabletop.  As more people start closing questions, and answerers learn that they will earn less rep by blindly answering questions, they will realize their greater purpose. Users that have an easier time earning (and not losing) rep will be selective answerers.

Comment: Regex tagged questions can be particularly squirrely to dupe close because of the snowflake requirements.  The most valuable SMEs on SO are the ones who can boil down the requirements to the "required technique" and find a duplicate that demonstrates that specific technique.  I believe regex questions that show no attempted pattern are Too Broad because they require multiple techniques -- which equate to multiple questions.  This is why a coding attempt is such a crucial part of the mcve.

Comment: I suppose I'll need to re-launch my proposal without the <5 answers block (as described in HolyBlackCat's upvoted answer) to see if the enough of the community would support **it** as a viable feature.  Part of me wonders if the same volume of downvotes would be received if a user other than me posted the same proposal.

Comment: ...Also, beneficial is that I personally won't get so many revenge votes while I curate.

Comment: I think banning new users from answering fresh questions off the fly will result in a huge efficiency drop in the site. Many users go through this phase as they familiarize and adapt to the culture and standards of the site. Yes, there are many brand new users who answer bad questions, or answer good questions poorly, but these account for such a small portion that this proposal feels completely... unnecessary. Allowing new users to answer quickly has also always been a staple of this site for quick communication and resolution of problems.

Comment: @Ryan I do not predict the same "efficiency drop".  I do agree that ALL new users go through a period of trial&error while adapting to the culture/standards -- this is not a bad thing, it is a natural thing.  My proposal pushes new/untrusted users to answer vetted-only questions until they've "steadied their ship" -- they can be super patient about posting insights and have no pressures to rush.  Users will be welcome to "answer quickly" on "fresh questions" after a very brief exclusion period.  Answering 5 questions (without a downvote) is VERY easy to satisfy -- easier than earning rep.

Answer (score 30):

I like the idea of checking the % of answers to closed questions.

But I'm strongly opposed to stopping users with <5 answers from answering questions newer than 4 hours. I believe this will scare away a lot of potential contributors, including potentially good contributors. We must assume users to be innocent until proven guilty.

Imagine this:

- You come to the site with years of programming experience, and want to share this experience.
- You see a challenging niche question that you can answer.
- The system tells you to wait 4 hours before answering.

If this happened to me, I'd think twice if I really want to stay or not.

Comment: No, as I said in my question, SO already has safeguards against allowing comment from new users -- this helps to reduce noise.  My proposal takes the exact same stance EXCEPT it is not dependent on rep gains.  Waiting 4 hours is nothing.  Waiting to hope to accumulate enough rep to unlock privileges -- that takes far longer.  We can even offer a quick filter on questions for new users so that they only see non-fresh questions.

Comment: I'm not downvoting your answer though.  If I had to remove the blocker from new users to get this proposal through, I would do so happily.  However, allowing new users to post on the freshest questions IS one of the major problems that I want to address.

Comment: @mickmackusa Currently the core functionality (asking and answering) is available to all users regardless of rep (unlike ancillary stuff like comments and flags), and I'd keep it this way. *"Waiting 4 hours is nothing."* Maybe, but it's yet another deterrent, even if a minor one. I sometimes try to pitch the idea of contributing to SO to my friends and colleagues and it rarely works. This would make it even harder.

Comment: Any system that cares about quality will need to limit the freedoms of its contributors to some degree.  My proposal is the best idea that I can come up with to help combat the rampant and growing mess that curators are struggling to keep up with.  If someone else has a better way to stop people posting answers to questions that should be closed, I'm all ears.  Honestly, I'm tired of reminding people to close closable questions -- especially people with hammers.

Comment: "We must assume users to be innocent until proven guilty." Seeing how even some of the most basic privileges must be earned on SO – I think we *don't* assume users to be innocent.

Comment: everybody is encouraged to contribute and it is for new users impossible to get high scores, also now a days you don't get upvotes like there use to be4, even good answers get onoly 1 or two upvotes, but easily a lot of downbvotes

Comment: @nbk the regex tag would love to disagree.

Comment: @nbk The C++ tag would also like to disagree. I heard we're commonly known as a rather obnoxious bunch, but my colleague rose from 0 to ~4k in ~3 months.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes there are tags that get more upvotes than others. so basically you can't compare c++ with mysql as a genral ban blockadeis not possible

Comment: " We can even offer a quick filter on questions for new users so that they only see non-fresh questions. " The problem with this is that good non-fresh questions are more likely well-answered already, likely within the hour of post. New users will see that the question is already answered and, more often than not, be discouraged from even trying to answer cause their answer will be pushed to the bottom

Comment: @Ryan I am almost exclusively a necroposter.  There are loads of opportunities to provide superior answers on old questions. In fact, I feel that the only safe place to look for unique questions is half a decade ago. There are literally millions of questions on Stack Overflow.  If you cannot find 5 questions in these millions, then I'd argue that all of the fresh questions that you find should be closed as duplicates and they shouldn't be answered by anyone anyhow.  (Oh, wait, I do hammer ~19 out of 20 of all new questions BECAUSE they are multi-duplicates.)

Answer (score 14):

The problem with this approach is that it only fixes the symptom.

The symptom of a problem like the Fastest Gun in the West is not borne out of the fact that answerers are always eager to answer questions.  To be fair, allowing users to answer questions as quickly as they can is an explicit feature of the site, and frankly, *any* site, only rivaled or superseded by real-time communication platforms.

The actual problem with users who jump into the fray to ask questions like that is that the questions are...fairly anemic.  A question that has an answer within a few Google search keystrokes gets 10 answers in two minutes because the asker didn't do enough due diligence in research or asking their question.  [They did not do enough research.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/261593/1)

So slowing down the answerers doesn't do anything to stymie the rush of crap questions that are available for people to answer.

Comment: Even if it only fixes symptoms.  It is a step in the right direction.  When answerers learn what is expected, they will better know how to behave when they become an asker.

Comment: No, it's a step *away* from where we want to go.  The site has had a very long and storied history of attributing a fix to the wrong group of users (think "Summer of Kindness", "Welcome Wagon", "New Question Wizard" (which doesn't show up often enough)), and this all kind of dances around the notion that the inquisitive people who come to Stack Overflow are just not that good at asking questions, and we move Heaven and Earth to accommodate them.  I'd also like to keep asking and answering separate; there are extremes but those two actions are separate and mutually exclusive.

Comment: I agree with you. (One of) the big problem(s) that needs to be worked on here is that we need to encourage/ train/ filter/ etc. for *better questions*, which will inevitably help the answer problem. This is related to the fact that starting in Feb. of 2020, SO had (for the first time ever) [more questions asked than answers given](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1446912/#graph), and that has yet to flip back. I wouldn't say that we *don't* have an answer problem, but we *definitely* have a question problem, and I think steps to address the latter would help the former.

Comment: Given, the idea that SO has a problem with LQ questions [isn't new by any stretch](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251913).

Comment: My proposal intends to reduce the LQ/FGITW posts on closable questions, reduce the time between question posting and question closing, and reduce the number of answers on closed questions.  These effects make it easier for curators to delete questions and answers before upvotes are collected and interfere.  By grooming volunteers to identify bad questions, there will begin a shift in question quality -- because only the best will survive.  Having more of the bad questions closed will lighten the review queue markedly -- not to mention curators manually deleting this pages

Comment: @mickmackusa:  If you're *only* predicated on the fact that users answer low quality questions, you are by definition only looking at half of the problem.  The number of people who are volunteering and willing to do this *at all* more than likely have a good sense of bad questions and know not to answer them.  An effort like this has to target the harder, more elusive population, which is...the askers.  This doesn't do that.

Comment: If people with the ability to post answers start prioritizing closing over answering, then we will have more asker bans.  Everything will naturally start flowing toward what you and I are seeking.

Comment: @mickmackusa:  Once again you underestimate how many people actually care to curate content.  The number of people who care to curate content is probably closer to 1% of the active user population of Stack Overflow.  If you can't move *that* needle then no amount of flailing or technical hoops you put in place are going to save us.

Comment: I agree, 1% feels accurate. How can people **care** if they are **unaware**.

Comment: "So slowing down the answerers doesn't do anything to stymie the rush of crap questions that are available for people to answer." Actually, it might. It makes the cost of getting an answer handed to you on a silver platter by asking on SO much higher than searching Google yourself for an hour. Maybe the limit should apply based on the *asker*'s reputation, though, rather than the answerer's.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it is good solution to problem. It will be hard to implement, it will punish people seemingly at random.

I can suggest softer approach. Remove all internet points awarded for answering closed question. By doing this we will remove incentive to jump on badly formulated question.

**EDIT:** It also add extra incentive to improve questions. You want to make sure that question you answer won't be closed, so you will try to save it, presumably by making it better.

There is a chance (as pointed in comments) that people will force those questions to stay alive by voting for them, but if it cause significant problem then we already lost. If we don't have enough manpower to curate questionse there are nothing we can do.

Comment: I could see this _really_ motivating people to unjustly reopen pages where they've answered.  Consider the fact that sometimes more recent pages are selected to close an older page (because the newer page is higher quality).  The people who earned hundreds of unicorn points on the older page will have them stripped away and they will be heartbroken (maybe).  At the moment, the only way that I can remove the rep gain from these bad answerers is to ensure that the question is closed and deleted.

Comment: What we can already do works better: delete questions which have no value in the long run, which in turn takes away any unwarranted reputation gains at the right time.

Comment: Yes, there is a risk that people will try to force reopen question, but it will require group effort. It boils down to the question: do we still have capacity to maintain quality of questions? If we don't, then all attempts are useless. Second part is potential problem too. But we may circumvent it by archiving those old question to prevent loss of points. I'm not too happy with this idea myself, but I just don't see any other options.

Comment: @E_net4theflagger we close such question, but rarely delete them. Should we delete questions aggressively?

Comment: While many question may evade the curation radar, initiatives towards this form of clean up do exist. The main problem with FGITW's is that they are likely to contribute to content which is not useful in the long run, and that content is candidate for removal.

Comment: @E_net4theflagger I don't think that this is main problem. In my opinion is the fact that they create cycle biggest problem. Answers to bad questions create incentive to ask more bad question. We have to break that cycle. We can't do much about askers, so only option is to suppress answers. OP propose to make it more difficult to answer them. I propose to remove incentive to answer them.

Answer (score 0):

Blocking is not an answer. A user must have the possibility to improve his/her answers/questions and his/her progress can only be seen in new questions and answers.

As you can see in this forum, the system of banning questions or answers is in place, and the users don't get why or have the nerve to read lengthy explanations, is how the system works.

The existing system has to be improved, so that old questions and answers, don't count, as it hinders people who have improved to go on in SO life and not everyone has the knowledge or confidence to answer in minutes.

So instead of banning and blocking more trainings possibilities for newbies and oldies. And maybe silver badges could delete answers by voting as I find often answers, that don't qualify for the harsh conditions of flagging, but they should also be removed.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. My proposal doesn't have anything to do with limiting a user's ability to "improve his answers /questions". My proposal doesn't not hold a user accountable for 100% of all of their answering decisions -- it is limited to their last 20 answers to check the current state of their contributions. There is no safeguard in place for answerers who fail to close pages properly. Solving this problem will not be done by affording silver badgers with more powers -- they are outnumbered by the other users who are not contributing optimally.

Comment: @mickmackusa I think it probably refers to [Allow old, poorly-asked questions to eventually age away for purposes of the question ban algorithm](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404510).

Comment: No, the people can't find any of thein formation they need, so we need more quiestions and answers, so that **everybody** can find their wanted information, even when they don't  speak the lingo. In the actual system it it hard to find anything . so the system must be improved. but as i stated in the first place with more basn and blocks, else SO has to evolve and change and evolve which it sadly isn't doing, we don't more restriction instead we need a system that allows every one to improve

Comment: „As you can see in this forum, the system of banning questions or answers is in place, and the users don't get why“ Do we really see that? The complaints on meta by confused ban „victims“ seem to be in the low single digit range per month. Are those all the people banned? Are those all the people willing to improve? Unless one knows how many people *dont* complain and how many people *do* get it, the few vocal complaints seem meaningless.

Comment: that is only because the most of them are already deleted, else you see a lot more of them and still nobody wants more bans or blocks