# Fresh Question Shielding -- now with no effect on users with less than 5 answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, low-quality-posts, post-ban

Based on the support for [@HolyBlackCat's preferred rule modification](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/410791/2943403) to [my previous meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410790/2943403), I'd like to crystalize the level of community support for my feature request in the name of progress.  I'm going to term this feature "**Fresh Question Shielding**" (FQS).

I am proposing that a feature be built into Stack Overflow which prevents users from answering fresh questions if they have a recent history of answering questions that should not have been answered -- evidenced by the fact that the community later closed the page.

Effectively, this should alter the perception of "*Low Hanging Fruit Questions*" to be "*Forbidden Fruit Questions*" which will make curation easier and reduce review queues.

You can visit my previous meta question to see the algorithmic rules for this feature, the benefits of its rollout, and commentary with the community.

Here is what has changed in my proposal:

1. Users with less than 5 answers will not be affected by FQS.
2. Users will always be allowed to self-answer -- even if affected by FQS.
3. Users will not be able to circumvent the FQS rules by marking one of their answers as community wiki.  This is because a wiki-answered page will still prevent the [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) from doing its excellent job.

For anyone who hasn't seen my previous proposal or doesn't feel like link-chasing, the crux of it is that **any users (regardless of rep) who have >= 60% of their most recent answers on closed questions will be prevented from answering questions that are less than 4 hours old**.  They can still flag, edit, vote, and comment on fresh questions.  They can even begin crafting answers to these fresh questions -- they just can't post them until the community has had sufficient time to vet the page.  To remove the FQS, users can either delete their answers on closed pages or answer non-fresh questions until their percentage drops below 60%.

This feature would go nicely with any combination of improvements to help pages, tiny rep gains for closing well, and/or any other community initiative to improve content curation.

Comment: I think this will entice some users to get around it with sock puppets: post as a new unregistered user, then trigger an automatic merge with the main account.

Comment: You mean a user will keep making new accounts after every 4 answers and then merging them into a master account?  Seems like a pretty simple abuse for mods to sniff out, don't you think?  There is also the hack of temporarily deleting an answer on a closed page to lift the FQS, then answer a new question, then undelete, but this again creates evidence of obvious fraud/mal-intent.  I see these attempts as easy to catch and easy to deal with.  In the end, this isn't meant to be a punishment on users/contributors; it is meant to be a way of making curation easier for caring SMEs and the Roomba.

Comment: We are discussing the algorithm in SOCVR at the moment.  Perhaps to prevent people temporarily deleting, the FQS would have a minimum duration of 24 hours to allow you to review all of your recent answers on closed pages and decide if you want to delete the answer, edit the question, or vote to reopen the question.  Then, after 24 hours, if your percentage is "good" then the FQS is lifted.

Comment: IMO, this is the wrong thing to focus efforts on. We wouldn't have this problem if less crap was allowed to be posted to being with. I mean, how can stuff like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68870855/how-to-create-sub-tabs-inside-vertical-tabs?noredirect=1) even post when we're supposed to have quality filters in place? More dev time on fixing the actual problem, not secondary side effects please.

Comment: What Mat said is also what most answers on your previous question mention. You're solving symptoms, not the cause of the issue.

Comment: Main issue with your proposals is that you are dealing with XY problem. No matter how you phrase or adjust your proposal, it will not be received well because it tries to solve the wrong problem, not the original one - poor questions. Additionally, it will be either too restrictive or it accomplishes nothing. Also, it creates whole level of new problems that will arise when people start circumventing the block.

Comment: I'm not convinced that grooming answerers to be better contributors is "the wrong problem". to fix  Improving the posting habits of answerers will significantly lighten the load for me as a curator.  @DalijaPrasnikar

Comment: Grooming better contributors, yes, absolutely. I am just not convinced this is the right way to go for it. Maybe focusing on showing some warning (to all users) when answering question that has negative votes, or it already has close votes or flags, it would  fare better. Main issue with poor quality posts, both questions and answers is that many people are not aware of the rules. If they know they are answering poor question that might get closed and removed along with their contribution, they (at least some of them) would start picking better questions.

Comment: Showing warnings does not solve problem with high reputation users that answer poor questions, but your proposal would most likely not prevent them from posting either way.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar If my proposal will not stop the >100k reppers, then it needs to be tweaked because they are my greatest source of frustration.  They know that they shouldn't answer, but they do anyhow.  I don't want to downvote their correct answers.  Commenting to compel then to remove their answer doesn't work.  They can tolerate many downvotes, because they have faith that the OP will accept their working solution. I want something automated that will compel them to delete their own answers to closed questions without **me** needing to be online to specifically poke them.

Comment: I took a look at few > 100k reppers known for answering questions instead of closing. Out of 10-20+ answers they post daily less than 10% of those questions were closed or even downvoted. There is no way to bring them down. And even if you successfully prevent them from answering question immediately, 4 hours is nowhere near enough to get all (or even fair amount) such questions closed.

Comment: I've been here a while and did a few things on the site. Some of them helpful, some of them curation tasks. When I started out I was very confused, and I spent a *very long time* trying to figure out the rules, until I came to realize that there are no hard rules.. just opinions. I've wanted to park my account a few times already. Had I been met with this when I was a new green sprout on the site, I'd have been *very* inclined to not waste my time. Perhaps the site would have been better off.. it's hard to tell, no?

Comment: The users that you seek to put a brake on, will not even notice this. But users that are new and trying and learning will be hit with an even greater wall.. They'll be barred from posting and watching someone with 20 Answers a day posting right in front of them, getting upvotes and green ticks. Those answerers aren't desperate. They're not trying to solve an issue "urgently". They're just trying to help someone else out.

Comment: @Scratte so what is your opinion overall?  Are you 100% against every part of my proposal? Should we throw up our arms and resign to the idea that the system has no way of grooming users to be better curators? I am not targeting just high rep users with this proposal -- this is an attempt to groom all users to be more discerning contributors.

Comment: I don't like the proposal because I think it will deter the very people you want to engage on the site. The problem is, as others have noted, the Questions. I made a suggestion a long time ago to use the queues we already have (Triage and First Posts) to postpone Questions being ready on the front page. They'll be pending until they pass the queue. No up/down voting, no answering. Just comments and pass/no pass. Anything that doesn't pass will auto-Roomba being 0-scored with no answers on them. It's aimed at the problem, not at the symptom. "My Questions is urgent" will effective be moot too.

Comment: You don't expect a wicked bottleneck in that scheme? @Scratte?

Comment: You mean 4,2K posts in the First Post queue? No.. I see no problems there. What is a problem is if 3,9K of those age away in the queue while they're being answered. Everyone posting a Question gets it on the front page immediately. There's no vetting process for Questions. There's only cleanup of removing them when we happen to come across them and find that they were bad. Those posts aren't from experienced users. The Triage queue is even filled with posts that some algorithm found to be problematic. We're not making very good use of those queues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A proposal to put all answerers on a path to curating better content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410790/a-proposal-to-put-all-answerers-on-a-path-to-curating-better-content)

Comment: I thought about the "wicked bottleneck" of yours a bit more. Imagine if people posting a Question gets told when they're "Reviewing their post" that "Posting this Question will send it to be vetted. This may take anywhere from a day to a month. While your post is being vetted, you cannot ask another Question. A lot of new Questions are duplicates and will be closed & removed during vetting. Are you sure this is not a duplicate and that you want to post this?" And that this restriction is just a "new user"-restriction, meaning old grumpy users, like me, are not affected by it.

Comment: @Scratte let's find a chat room to bounce around some ideas (I'm not available right now).  I am deeply in favor of change because the problems that SO currently has are not self-solving.  I've got a few ideas about handling new questions myself.  Perhaps we can craft something viable and inspiring together.

Comment: I see that there are 3 duplicate closure votes on my question.  Every time a vote is lodged, I am greeted with a message that asks if the question is a duplicate of my previous question (which I explicitly linked at the start of my question). I click No, then the UI asks me to edit my question to state how this question is different from the previous.  Well, this question **already** clearly states what has changed since the last proposal, so there is nothing to edit.  Please do not use close votes as super-downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think 4 hours at 60% FQS is **still very generous** (this proposal has my support).

[67.6% of posts have “solidified” their status in the first hour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302970).

- A user who consistently answers 60% dups/typos/etc is obviously doing something wrong. There's no way someone can claim this is being *too strict* if you're tolerating 50%/50% FQS users only the most chronic *doesn't understand/care about close criteria* users are affected. (**This proposal takes care of business while being tolerant**.)

This would give the community 4 hours to react. It's reasonable for the most blatant cases, see [fig D. 90% of questions that get closed on Stack Overflow now get closed in under 2 days; 50% get closed in less than an hour!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223)

This dissuades obvious cases of [recidivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recidivism).

Comment: Wow.  You found some meta gold there.  Good researching.  If the proposal proves to be too generous, we can always tighten the threshold.  Just like when the number of close votes needed to close a page was reduced to better suit community goals.

Comment: @mickmackusa vintage selection, from my personal bookmark cellar.

Comment: Did I miss something or is that last one from 2015? Wasn't the curator to Question ratio better back then?

Comment: @Scratte it was but this is the most recent official overview I've seen on the issue. (There have been comments pointing to a 50%/50% review queue efficiency and some can be deduced from *a year in closure*, but regarding closure timing this is the best I've found.)

Answer (score 12):

I like the idea of trying to encourage answering effort to be directed at better questions.  I like the idea of trying to discourage rep farming through FGITW answering as a way to improve content quality.

But at least with the thresholds you propose here, it won't make a difference, simply because only a handful of people actually cross the threshold you propose.

If we assume that the bulk of the problem is from people posting a *lot* and use two weeks (starting 2021-08-01, two weeks before the last SEDE dump) as the threshold for "recent", require at least 5 questions  in that time period, and find all users who would be affected, there are a total of [6 users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1451193/fresh-question-shielding-data?StartDate=2021-08-01) who would be affected by this, who've answered a total of 21 closed questions in that time.  If we look back further, say to [anything since May](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1451193/fresh-question-shielding-data?StartDate=2021-05-01), we get 9 users. Looking [back to the start of the year](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1451193/fresh-question-shielding-data?StartDate=2021-01-01) finds 18.

None of these people have answered more than 6 closed questions in that time period.

Comment: I was more concerned that this proposal would not be well received if the requirements were more strict.  I didn't necessarily want to design a feature that applies the FQS to 50% of the community. I think the mere threat of FQS could be effective in improving awareness. How much would _you_ like to see the algorithm tightened?  What do you think is "firm but fair"?  Did you toy with the percentages yet?  Does it become "better" to you at a lower threshold?

Comment: Hmm.  While I really appreciate someone taking the time to craft a SEDE query, I wonder how closely it reflects reality.  I mean, my algorithm groups by most recent 5, 10, and 20.  Over a span of time, there will be points where questions are deleted.  If you change the start date to Jan 1 of this year, then you get 18 users.  On users with 8 answers, my algorithm ignores the 3 oldest and only looks at the most recent 5 (until they hit the 10 answers mark).

Comment: @mickmackusa: How can you wonder how closely this SEDE query reflects reality? This is literally a query on a snapshot of the live data. Your proposed rules just don't return that many users.

Comment: Well, there are pages that are Roomba'ed or removed by human curators in the time between.  Also, as I said the algorithm in the sql is not exactly aligned with the 5, 10, and 20 grouping in my proposal.  Again, if this proposal needs to become _more_ strict in identifying "bad answerers", then I am happy to change the algorithm.  Don't let fine tuning the algorithm be the thing that destroys the proposal.  Recommend a better algorithm if you have a better one.  I am very open to modification of the proposal -- I am seeking constructive advancement.

Comment: I think running 50% dups on a 2 week window is too narrow.

Answer (score 6):

This won't solve the root cause of why FGITW answers are attractive to a certain group of users: **Easy rep.**

Even if you block some users from answering for a few hours, there are easily 2-3 other users that still dump a quick and easy answer on the typical FGITW questions.

This rep incentive needs to disappear for questions that get closed within a short time of being posted. (Which has been [discussed plenty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357021/reputable-people-keep-answering-duplicates-whats-the-solution) on Meta)

Blocking a *few* of the answerers isn't going to change much.

Comment: _"Lose rep on closure, or maybe even a penalty"_ I disagree 100%. You _already_ lose rep on _deletion_. If the question is closed because it's off-topic, well, it should be deleted anyway. If it's closed because it's a dup, it should be deleted if it's a frequent dup. Otherwise, it's not the answerer's fault that they (at least plausibly) didn't know about the duplicate.

Comment: @41686d6564 plenty of FGITW questions get closed but not deleted. Answerers regularly walk away with 20-50 rep there. Especially on popular tags like [tag:javascript] there are users that do nothing but hunt down low hanging fruit to get easy rep, with no regard for dupe closure. They're wilfully ignoring the fact that the question is a duplicate.

Comment: @41686d6564 I've also removed that line from my answer, as that penalty really isn't the focus of my answer on this suggestion.

Comment: Either they should be deleted (in which case, the problem is that they aren't) or they shouldn't (e.g., signpost duplicate); in that case, it's not the answerer's fault as I said above. If you want to encourage users to go searching for dup targets instead of answering, then FRs like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394048/8967612) need to be implemented. I personally try to find duplicates for as many posts as I can, but we can't realistically expect all/most users to spend time looking for duplicates without incentive when the alternative (answering) has plenty of incentive.

Comment: I have to agree with Cerbus on this one @41686d6564.  Because closed questions still allow bad answerers to retain rep, I am even more motivated to vote to delete closed questions in an attempt to "teach them" to stop answering closable questions.  My problem with perpetual "work" is that it doesn't scale enough given that there are far more sloppy answerers than good curators AND it takes multiple humans to delete a closed page containing answers.  With no answers on a closed page, the Roomba can do what is good/right automatically.

Comment: @41686d6564 which is why I'm sayin that at very least the incentive should be _removed_. The "penalty" is just something that was also discussed in this context, and is barely a footnote in this answer.

Comment: Generally, dupes _shouldn't_ be deleted, as they serve as signposts to the core question. But as @mickmackusa mentions, these questions are now getting deleted to do something about the rep gain.

Comment: @mickmackusa Again, if the question meets the criteria for deletion, go ahead and delete it, of course. OTOH, voting to delete questions that shouldn't be deleted (e.g., duplicates) just to punish answerers (who may or may have not known that there's a duplicate) is a form of abuse. This happens quite frequently in certain tags and has been discussed on meta in the not-so-distant past.

Comment: I'm seeing 2 users agree that the core of the problem is the rep incentive on obvious duplicates... Curious how this answer is at -2.

Comment: How about this then - anyone who answers questions that are dupes of anything in the first page if the FAQ/wiki has 10% of their rep deducted.  Make it retroactive.

Comment: @Cerbrus My reply was about _both_ the penalty _and_ removing the rep. If someone spends time writing a good answer to a question that later turns out to be a dup (not a frequent one), why punish them? Especially if they genuinely didn't know about (or couldn't find) the dup target.

Comment: @41686d6564 FGITW answers aren't good. Theýe dime a dozen easy solutions to easy problems that get asked on a daily, or even hourly basis. They're posted by users that don't give a flip about the question being a dupe. Users that have made gaming the system a sport. There are users out there with 6-digit rep that do nothing but stamp out easy answers to obvious duplicates. __That__ is the behavior we're trying to stop here. Those users know -very- well that the question they're answering is a dupe.

Comment: I didn't up or down vote this answer, but my position is that this proposal IS intended to make FGITW users pause to consider IF questions should be answered.  If they show a pattern of making bad decisions, then the FQS intentionally keeps them out of range of those easy upvotes.  They can still answer questions that the community has vetted, but the rep gains will be slowed down.

Comment: @Cerbrus We agree about the problem but disagree about the solution. Yes, there are many users who fit your description. So, what do we do? We delete questions that should be deleted, not impose a penalty (including rep removal) based on question closure. We just need more users who vote to delete off-topic questions and frequent duplicates (and _only_ frequent ones).

Comment: @41686d6564: Then it's just an arms race. You're incentivizing 2 conflicting actions. Remove the incentive for the bad behaviour, and you're set.

Comment: @41686d6564  If someone crafts an excellent answer that adds unique value to SO, but it is on a page that is dupe closed, then the solution is simple.  Transfer the answer to the dupe target (and tailor it to that page's scope) and delete the answer on the closed page -- everybody wins (even Stack Overflow).  Getting better eggs in fewer baskets is EXACTLY what Stack Overflow needs.  If the _answer_ is not unique to SO, then we can flush it safely too.  When I am closing pages, there are often >=5 dupes that I can list.  There is waaaaaaay too much redundancy on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

You would have the same problem as you had with your old request.

Users must have the possibility to evolve and they can only do that when they try to answer questions and get hints how to improve them.

When they are really bad at it and continue to do bad answers or questions, they get banned.

Also I would remind you that there is a wast knowledge outside, and everyone can be good at something and bad at others.

Still with the actual system of bans, it still needs improvement.

High reputation points and gold/silver badge users should be able to delete bad answers by voting on them, but the people that can actually do it are small in numbers.

Comment: My proposal absolutely does give users a chance to evolve.  It is meant to alert them if they are not evolving.  I don't know of anyone answering closed questions getting an answer ban.  My algorithm is forgiving; feedback suggests that it is too forgiving to be effective.  As a gold badger, I don't want more powers.  I am already hated and revenge voted enough for the powers and actions that I take.  No.  I want the system to be the one that keeps people in line so that I can enjoy SO more. Not to mention spend less time curating.

Comment: it is teh same request as the last time, and i wrote alimost the same as last time, a system is in place and needs adjustment, but increasing level of contributing is against the principles of this site and as you can see in the votes also of the  menbers

Comment: i type too fast and don't check the post, sorry, i have usually to many things in my mind, and your proposal is striking a site that irritates me, massively, i am against your proposal and would always be against it. this should be closed as a dupe, as it makes teh same bad request.